# Get all unique values in excel columns using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter my data to write only non-repeating values in an array for every group to white they belong.
I am running into the error ByRef argument type mismatch.
Here is my code:

```
Sub Start_Time2()

    Dim UGs(1 To 3) As Long
    
    Dim r1 As Range
    Set r1 = Worksheets("s1").Range("F:F")

    UGs(1) = 480
    UGs(2) = 490
    UGs(3) = 455
    
    Size = 1
    
    For Each ug In UGs
        For Each row In r1
            Dim sng() As String
            If IsInArray(ug, sng) = True Then
                ReDim Preserve sng(Size)
                sng(Size) = row
                Size = Size + 1
            End If
        Next row
    Next ug
    
End Sub
```

I am using the custom function IsInArray which I found online to check if the value is already in my array, but it seems that my ug variable does not work.

```
Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) = stringToBeFound Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    IsInArray = False

End Function
```

Here is my test data:
[image]

Comment: Use `Dictionary`, it will save your time

Answer (score 0):

As for the ByRef argument type mismatch error - it occurred because `ug` has `Variant` type (undeclared variables have Variant type by default) and `stringToBeFound` argument has `String` type.
To get rid of this error, specify, for example:

```
Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
```

Use the `Option Explicit` instruction on the first line of the module to automatically check for variable declarations.

Also, to handle the range `F:F`, i.e. 1048576 cells seems redundant, it should be specified.

And, of course, selection of unique values is better to do with [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) as @Kin Siang wrote or [Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/collection-object).